# How get time difference between current time and set time of next day?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I have designed an application in which i am sending a push notification. That notification generate on the base of time interval. That time interval calculate from difference of current time and selected time of next day. So i get a problem that is how i set time for next days which i want to set? And second problem is how get difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code to get the time interval to a time tomorrow:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Get today date
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

// Set the time tomorrow
components.hour = 12;
components.minute = 30;
components.day = components.day + 1;

NSDate *tomorrow = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"tomorrow: %@", tomorrow);

NSTimeInterval timeTillTomorrow = [tomorrow timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"timeTillTomorrow: %.0f seconds", timeTillTomorrow);
```